# How to bind values programmatically in c# for windows phone?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I need some values to bind in c# as they are posted through XML Serialization to the next screen. In the code below `ehvalue3` should be posted through XML. It's working fine when binding is specified in XAML but I need to specify binding in c# code.

How to do this?

```
private void EHSelect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {                
            int ehvalue1 = EHMeterSelector.SelectedItem;
            int ehvalue2 = EHCentimeterSelector.SelectedItem;
            if (ehvalue1 == 0)
            {
                ehvalue1 = EHMeterSelector.DefaultValue;
            }
            EHeight_btn.Content = ehvalue1 + " ft " + ehvalue2+ " in";         

            float ehvalue3 = float.Parse(string.Format("{0}.{1}", ehvalue1.ToString(), ehvalue2.ToString()));      

SaveUser();
        }
```

Comment: please take a look at [this article - Example 3](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/talking-about-data-binding-in-wp7--coding4fun-textboxbinding-helper-in-depth) and this [result set](https://www.google.com/search?q=wp7+bind+programmatically&oq=wp7+bind+programmatically&aqs=chrome..69i57.4600j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=wp7+bind+programmatically). Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you look at something like [this](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Data_Binding_to_controls_on_Windows_Phone) guide which should help you.

In a nutshell, you need to:

- Ensure that your C# class implements INotifyPropertyChanged.
- That changes to your properties raise an appropriate PropertyChanged event.
- That the DataContext of your XAML Control is set to the C# class.
- Binding to properties can then be something like `Text="{Binding myProperty,Mode=TwoWay}"`

Comment: he needs to bind programmatically, if I got the question correctly